# returning a custom Array list and getting it in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created a class for all API calls, and when I call a method in that class it will return a custom ArrayList. from that returned list I want to extract only the vehicle names
**ApiCalls.kt**

```
class ApiCalls {
val client = OkHttpClient()
val list: ArrayList<VehicleListModel>? = null
public fun getEnquiryList(id:String): ArrayList<EnquiryModel>? {
    return null
}
public fun getVehicleList(): ArrayList<VehicleListModel> {

    val body = FormBody.Builder()
            .build()
    val request = Request.Builder()
            .post(body)
            .url(URLs.URL_GET_VEHICLE_LIST)
            .build()
    val callGetVehicleList = client.newCall(request)
    callGetVehicleList?.enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
            if (call == null || call.isCanceled)
                return
            }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
            if (call == null || call.isCanceled)
                return
            val resp = response?.body()?.string()

            try {


                val jo = JSONObject(resp)
                val message = jo.getJSONArray("VehicleModelList")

                for (i in 0 until message.length()) {
                    val json = message.getJSONObject(i)
                    val vehicleListId = json.getString("_id")
                    val vehicleListName =json.getString("vehicle_model_name")
                    val vehicle = VehicleListModel(vehicleListId, vehicleListName)
                    if (list != null) {
                        list.add(vehicle)
                    }
                   Log.e("....................",vehicleListId)
                }

            } catch (e: Exception) {

            }
        }
    })

    return list!!
}
```

}

this class is called from my fragment

```
list= ApiCalls().getVehicleList()
    for (i in 0 until list.size)
    {
        labels.add(list[i].vehicleName)
    }
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,labels)
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

  vehiclelist.adapter = adapter
```

I am getting this error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: abc.com.app, PID: 23077
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
```

hope I have cleared the problem

Comment: check doing Log whether your list is getting data or not

Comment: iam getting value for list in ApiCalls But not to Fragment

Comment: If you get time, please improve the formatting of the code in your question for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
if (list != null) {
    list.add(vehicle)
}
```

`list` is `null` to begin with, `list.add` is never called.

You must first initialise `list`, and then the above if statement will work as expected.

So before the above if statement, somewhere, do `list = ArrayList<VehicleListModel>()`

**I am referring to the `list` inside the `ApiCalls` class**

Comment: iam getting values list in ApiCalls but not in Fragment

Answer (score 0):

You must include all your code in ApiCalls clas inside :

```
class ApiCalls {
 companion object {
    //code
 }
}
```

this is the equivalent of static in Kotlin, since you don't instantiate objects of type ApiCalls.
Also you don't need parenthesis when you call:

```
list= ApiCalls.getVehicleList()
```